# Check column if has the same value on all the rows

Tags: mysql

How do I check if a column has all the rows the same value?

I don't think this will work.

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE value = 1
```

I want to make, by time each row will turn from 0 to 1 till every row has value 1, if all the values are 1 to turn all in 0

```
id value
1  1
2  1
3  1
4  1
5  1
6  1
7  1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this query :-

```
select count(value) from table where value =0;
```

if rows return `count` is `zero` that means there are no zeroes in that column.

Answer (score 12):

You can try to use distinct

```
select count(distinct column) FROM table
```

If the result is 1 then it means there is only same value present in the column else there are different values present in your column.

Comment: Yes but if the result is 1 that could also mean that 0 is in entire column. I would have to double check if 0 exist in any row...

Comment: @Alex_TNT:- No if it shows 1 then it means that the count of distinct value  in your column is 1 not the literal value 1

Answer (score 2):

Use `count`

```
SELECT count(value) as total FROM table
```

if total > 1 than more than on value